# Mutating a slice field of a struct even though all methods are defined with value receivers

Tags: go, pointers, slice

> 6.2 Methods with a Pointer Receiver
>
> If all the methods of a named type T have a receiver type of T itself
> (not *T ), it is safe to copy instances of that type; calling any of
> its methods necessarily makes a copy. For example, time.Duration
> values are liberally copied, including as arguments to functions. But
> if any method has a pointer receiver, you should avoid copying
> instances of T because doing so may violate internal invariants. For
> example, copying an instance of bytes.Buffer would cause the original
> and the copy to alias ( §2.3.2 ) the same underlying array of bytes.
> Subsequent method calls would have unpredictable effects.
>
> (The Go Programming Language Alan A. A. Donovan · Brian W. Kernighan)

I understand the general meaning of the quote, but I am wondering whether it's correct to say that is safe to copy instances of that type.

If a struct has a slice/map field then all copies receive their own copies of the pointers to the backing array/hashmap so it is still possible to mutate those data structures.

Even though all the methods might be defined using value receivers, we can break the internal state of the struct.

I understand why that happens, but doesn't that possibility contradict what is written in that paragraph above?

Copying values might have unwanted consequences regardless of the method receivers and also depends on the field types.

What am I missing here?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    s []string
}

func main() {
    original := T{s: []string{"original"}}
    copycat := original
    copycat.s[0] = "copycat"
    fmt.Println(original.s[0] == "copycat") // true
}
```

Comment: You seem to understand what the underlying problem is here, is this just a comment about the wording of the documentation? Yes it is "safe" to access the copy of the struct, but the backing array in the slice is not part of the struct.

Comment: @JimB, it's not a comment per se, but rather my attempts to make sure I understand the paragraph. Thank you for answering. I guess the problem is I find it a bit counterintuitive that "the backing array is not part of the slice". That also destroys the original internal state of the struct in some way that was copied, doesn't it?

Comment: Slices are a fundamental data structure in Go, so you should be very familiar with how they work when using them: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro. Copying the struct does exactly what it says it does and nothing else, there is no ulterior intent, the slice is passed just as if itself were passed by value (which is is)

Comment: I didn't mean that I do not understand what a slice in Go is. I know that is essentially a header where one of the fields is a pointer to the backing array, and this is why modifying the elements is reflected in the copies (but changing the len and cap is not). 

What I am asking, however, is whether it is correct to state that this internal integrity is defined by the receiver type. The behavior itself is completely clear to me, but I find it hard to understand the explanation in the book. 

(sorry for the confusion, I might be formulating awfully)

Comment: @DonDraper  If *all* methods on a type have value receivers, then copying the value will not violate internal constraints. If *one or more* methods have pointer receivers, it's possible that copying the object will violate an internal constraint.

Comment: @BaytaDarell, I guess modifying the backing array of a slice field is not considered to be "internal constraints", right?

Comment: @DonDraper Think of the internal invariants as assumptions that type's methods make about the state of the value.  A modification to a backing array does not necessarily violate the assumptions made by a type's methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm neither Donovan nor Kernighan, so I can't definitively say what they were trying to communicate here, but my understanding is not that "using value receivers *makes* copying safe", but rather "using value receivers *indicates* copying is safe". You are correct that any pointer field, or any field which contains a pointer field (including slices and maps), will make copying unsafe; I believe what the authors are trying to get across is that an API which uses a value receiver is indicating to its consumers that no such fields exist.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this interpretation makes sense. It seems that my understanding of "internal constraints/invariants" is different. My understanding is that getting modified slice items in your field is also part of the "internal invariants"